# Center glyph vertically within its parent

Tags: css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I have an icon I want to **center vertically** in its parent container, but as it appears, the glyph falls outside of its container, [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pzgc7wLy/), hacking it with absolute positioning is just so cumbersome. I have also tried various tricks with flexbox layout to no avail.

```
<div class="icon-wrap">
    <i class="caret-up icon"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.icon {
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 60px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.icon::before {
  content: "\1F891";
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Also the extra 'padding' at the top of the glyph seems to be part of it (somehow?), what I want is a *light-weight* solution that will position the caret in the middle of its container.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon with a div or other element...

```
<div class="icon-wrap">
  <i class="caret-up icon"></i>
</div>
```

...then apply flexbox layout to that wrapper with `display: flex`. Now you can perfectly center the icon in the wrapping element with `align-items` and `justify-content` rules:

```
.icon-wrap {
  display: flex; /* flexbox layout */
  align-items: center; /* horizontal centering */
  justify-content: center; /* vertical centering */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this already and it doesn't seem to work, I have update the jsfiddle so you can check it out